# php edit and save word and excel files

Tags: php

I am trying to build a module which will manage following features:

- Upload MS Word or MS Excel file
- View and Edit the Uploaded MS Word or MS Excel file
- Save and Re-Upload the same file with latest changes

I want to know is this possible using PHP? Is there any plugin that I can use to achieve these features?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/PHPOffice
In this github account there are the tools which you need.

Comment: Does this library offers to edit and exists docx file?

Comment: Yes, there is `PHPWord` library. It does reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to edit excel and word document in the browser, you will have to go with google docs (that just launch their service) or with Office Online Server or Office 365.

To be able to manage your files you need to implement a WOPI server to be able to send and receive those files either to Office Online or google docs. (This is how all major cloud storage companies does it).

This is an medium/hard implementation and takes some knowledge reading and time.

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2016/05/04/office-online-server-now-available/

https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/